# Can't manage to get working dynamic form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, dhtml

I'm making a dynamic html form with jQuery.
It is a form for measuring air in each room for ventilation.

I need two inputs: Room name and Air volume value.
My task is to dynamically add a line with Select and Input and Remove buttons. Later on it should be submitted to the php processor.

My plan was to clone div and it looked that it works, but I get problems with Select input field.
Select menu in the original Div works, but the i clone div Select value would't change.
I was looking around for the solution, but I haven't managed to find out.
By pressing remove button I need to remove current DIV with elements. That doesn't work either:)

I'm not sure if I'm in correct way of making all that happen, because I'm just starting out with jQuery.
Thanks for any help!

Here is the code for the form:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function Addonemoretilluft() {
    $('#tilluft_line').clone().insertAfter("#tilluft_line"); 
}

function Removetilluft() {
    $('#page').remove("#tilluft_line"); 
}


$(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#add_tilluft").click(function(){
      Addonemoretilluft();
    });  

    $("#remove_tilluft").click(function(){
      Removetilluft();
    });    
});
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<div class="page" data-iscroll="" id="page">      
               <form action="handle.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="tilluft_form"> 

                  <div id="tilluft_line" class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div id="select_value" class="ui-block-a">
                         <select name="tilluft_name[]" id="tilluft_name[]" data-mini="true">
                            <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
                            <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
                            <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
                            <option value="val4">Val 4</option>    
                         </select>  
                        </div>
                        <div id="input_value" class="ui-block-b">
                            <input name="tilluft_value[]" id="tilluft_value[]" data-mini="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:35px;">
                            <a href="#" id="remove_tilluft" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a id="add_tilluft"  href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="add" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Add one more</a> 
               </form>  
               <input type="submit" form="tilluft_form" value="Submit Form" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"/>
          </div>​
</body>
```

Test version http://jsfiddle.net/D4MPu/

Comment: You are cloning attribute id elements too. ID must be unique on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is that, when you clone the line, you are duplicating an ID value. Per the [HTML spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html):

> Errors that would likely result in scripts failing in hard-to-debug
>   ways Some errors are intended to help prevent script problems that
>   would be hard to debug.
>
> This is why, for instance, it is non-conforming to have two id
>   attributes with the same value. Duplicate IDs lead to the wrong
>   element being selected, with sometimes disastrous effects whose cause
>   is hard to determine

this is not allowed. ID elements **must** be unique. Instead, use something like a class (which you can have duplicates) to fix this problem, or change the ID (although, I would recommend the use of a class).